Adding new row to the Django template table
I have a simple table generated from Django template variable:
{% for object in object_list %}
    <tr>
        <td class="c9">{{object.first_name}}</td>
        <td class="c9">{{object.last_name}}</td>
        <td class="c9">{{object.tel}}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}

I'm making insert to this model and the server side is done, but how to add a new row in top of this table?
With this method: var row = table.insertRow(0)?
or can I change this variable 'object_list' and row will be added automatically?
This simple solution 'var row = table.insertRow(0);' is not adding columns with CSS classes.

You can add the css classes manually. But I don't see much reason to add it to every td, why not put it in the table <table class="c9"> and apply the selector as td.c9 tr td { ...} instead of td.c9 { ... }.


This simple solution var row = table.insertRow(0); is not adding columns with CSS classes.

You probably don't have to add the css class in the first place.
Instead you could use:
<table class="c9">
    <!-- … -->
</table>
and then in the css selector use:
table.c9 tr td {
    /* … */
}
instead of:
td.c9 {
    /*  … */
}
